# Is this possible to bring back a live cd session after an accidental CD-ROM unplugging for a while?

Tags: ubuntu, livecd

There was a power outage when I was using a live cd on my laptop with external CD - ROM connected to wall power supply, so cd was unaccessible and maybe unmounted for a second. Then the power came back and the OS seems to be alive but the X desktop is just a background image and TTYs are avaible (I can disply all of them) and I can type but can't execute anything - I can only see errors like: `SQUASHFS error: unable to read` and `INFO: task XXX blocked for more than 120 seconds`.

Is there any way or chance to get access to virtual filesystem or just unblock it yet without rebooting? My live cd is Ubuntu 10.04.

Answer (score 0):

Not likely. I have tried before and didn't have any success.